# How to add object into array in file in cypress

Tags: arrays, cypress

I have a file `demoJ.json`. It contains an array of objects

```
[{
  "name": "autoTest146",
  "email": "autoTest146@mail.com",
  "pass": "password"
}]
```

Everytime if it needs necessary, I generate new user and their credentials. I want to add them into this file to use them in future tests.
How can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just to rewrite each time that file, simply use `writeFile` util:

```
cy.writeFile('/path/to/file.json', userObject)
```

In case you need to append and keep old ones, then go with `readFile`, `writeFile` and spread aperator:

```
cy.readFile('/path/to/file.json').then(userList => {
    cy.writeFile('/path/to/file.json', [...userList, newUserObject])
})
```

Comment: I don't want to rewrite, I want to add records

Comment: then the second approach is the way to go ;)

Comment: Thank you, Alex. but I got file like with arrays in array

Comment: You have to make sure your second argument,  `newUserObject` is an object. I do suspect your it is an object inside an array. If so, just explicitly indicate it by index: `[...userList, newUserObject[0]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readFile` and `writeFile` cypress methods to do this. Something like:

```js
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/demoJ.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err)
  }
}).then((data) => {
  data[0].name = 'new Name'
  data[0].email = 'new Email'
  data[0].pass = 'new Password'
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/demoJ.json.json', JSON.stringify(data))
})
```